# How to use jQuery to change the interface according to the selected entry

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change pop a text up when different entries are selected. This is my drop down list code.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <select class="form-control" id="ltype" name="ltype">
      <option value="">Select the Leave Type</option>
           <option value="training">training</option>
           <option value="conference">conference</option>
           <option value="vacation">vacation</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="letter1" style="float:right; padding-right:70px;color:#FF0000;"></div>
```

This is my jQuery script.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('letter1').html('text entered');
    $("#ltype").change(function(){
        var ltyp = (this).val();
        if($ltyp == 1){
            $('letter1').html('one');
        }else if($ltyp == 2){
            $('letter1').html('two');
        }else if($ltyp == 3){
            $('letter1').html('three');
        }
    });
});</script>
```

This does not give any result. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) `var $ltyp = $(this).val();` if you use `$ltyp`. 2) Values in your `select` are `training`, `conference`, `vacation`, not `1, 2, 3`.

Answer (score 1):

Youre going wrong  in this code. You need to remove the `$` in ur conditional

**Jquery**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('letter1').html('text entered');
    $("#ltype").change(function(){
        var ltyp = (this).val();
        if(ltyp == 1){ //just remove the `$` in condition
            $('letter1').html('one');
        }else if(ltyp == 2){ //just remove the `$` in condition
            $('letter1').html('two');
        }else if(ltyp == 3){ //just remove the `$` in condition
            $('letter1').html('three');
        }
    });
});</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're gonna check for the selectedIndex, you shouldn't use `$(this).val()` rather use `$(this).prop('selectedIndex')`.

See sample **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qy6to087/)** that checks by the dropdown's selected Index.

```
    $('#letter1').html('text entered');

    $("#ltype").change(function() {
      var ltyp = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
      if (ltyp == 1) {
        $('#letter1').html('one');
      } else if (ltyp == 2) {
        $('#letter1').html('two');
      } else if (ltyp == 3) {
        $('#letter1').html('three');
      }
    });
```

See **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qy6to087/1/)** that checks by the dropdown's selected Index and gets the corresponding value.

```
    $('#letter1').html('text entered');

    $("#ltype").change(function() {
      var ltyp = $(this);
      if (ltyp.prop('selectedIndex') == 1) {
        $('#letter1').html(ltyp.val());
      } else if (ltyp.prop('selectedIndex') == 2) {
        $('#letter1').html(ltyp.val());
      } else if (ltyp.prop('selectedIndex') == 3) {
        $('#letter1').html(ltyp.val());
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains errors.
You add a '$' to your variable and miss the '#' when use jQuery selector.
You can try this one:

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#letter1').html('text entered');
    $("#ltype").change(function(){
        var ltyp = $(this).val();
        ltyp && $('#letter1').text(ltyp);
    }); 
});
</script>
```